# React-native animated.event custom onScroll listener

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In official react-native documentation there is a section about `Animated.event` method. As example they use following code:

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
   // scrollX = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
   [{ nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset: {
          x: scrollX
        }
      }
    }]
 )}
```

I would like to map correct values to `Animated.event` method and I would also like to map onScroll callback parameters to my own callback. Basically I would like to do something like this:

```
onScroll={(event) => {
  myOwnCallback(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)
  Animated.event(
    // scrollX = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
    [{nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset: {
          x: scrollX
        }
      }
    }]
  )
}}
```

Could you please explain how to do that?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you look at the source code:

````
/**
   * Takes an array of mappings and extracts values from each arg accordingly,
   * then calls `setValue` on the mapped outputs.  e.g.
   *
   *```javascript
   *  onScroll={Animated.event(
   *    [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: this._scrollX}}}]
   *    {listener},          // Optional async listener
   *  )
   *  ...
   *  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
   *    null,                // raw event arg ignored
   *    {dx: this._panX},    // gestureState arg
   *  ]),
   *```
   *
   * Config is an object that may have the following options:
   *
   *   - `listener`: Optional async listener.
   *   - `useNativeDriver`: Uses the native driver when true. Default false.
   */
  event,
````

This is how I made it work:

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
  {
    useNativeDriver: true,
    listener: event => {
      const offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
      // do something special
    },
  },
)}
```

Comment: How do you add an function as a listener here? I tried binding it in there but it doesn't seem to fire. Any further explanation about this?

Answer (score 3):

Write handler function like:

```js
    handleScroll = (e) => {
        console.log(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
    }
```

and you can add `listener` like this:

```js
    Animated.event(
       [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
       { listener: (event) => this.handleScroll(event) }
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't get Michal's solution to work for me. Ended up going with this

```js
onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
               animatedY.setValue(nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
               // other actions to be performed on scroll
         }}
```